# Why adding a date range filter disables aggs?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents of the type

```
{
  "host-ip": "192.168.0.1",
  "HOST_END_iso": "2016-02-19T09:30:41+01:00"
}
```

I successfully query ES to get one random entry and an aggregation of `host-ip`

```
{
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "size": 1,
   "aggs": {
      "rating": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "host-ip",
            "size": 0,
            "shard_size": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I now want to filter the results and get the documents between two dates. The `query` part gets more complicated:

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "query": {
               "match_all": {}
            },
            "terms": {
               "range": {
                  "HOST_END_iso": {
                     "gt": "2015-02-19T09:30:41+01:00",
                     "lt": "2016-02-19T09:30:41+01:00"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "size": 1
   },
   "aggs": {
      "rating": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "host-ip",
            "size": 0,
            "shard_size": 0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**There is one record returned, but no aggregations. Why?**

Please note that I had to move the `size` which limits the number of returned elements into the scope of the first `query`. **I do not understand why I need to do that**: if I leave it at the same level as `query` and `aggs` (like in the first -successful- example), I am not limited anymore to 1 element but I get the default 10 (so `size` is not taken into account and I still do not get aggs anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is ill-formed in many places: here is the correct one

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "HOST_END_iso": {
            "gte": "2015-02-19T09:30:41+01:00",
            "lte": "2016-02-19T09:30:41+01:00"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "rating": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "host-ip",
        "size": 0,
        "shard_size": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The main issue was the `terms/range` filter, you need either one but not both.

Comment: Thank you. After bouncing back and forth in the docs, I ended up -as you mention- mixing up [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-terms-query.html) and [range](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) while they live at the same level in the `query`.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Comment: I did not *figure it out*. It is thanks to your answer I *understood* where I was wrong :)

Comment: Ok, then, I'm glad that helped :)